# Which piece of code is generally more accepted?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering which of the pieces of code below are generally more accepted or maybe even better:

```
function doStuff(check) {
    if(!check) {
        return "blablabla";
    } else if (check >= 5) {
        return "blablabla";
    } else {
        return "blablabla";
    }
}
```

or

```
function doStuff(check) {
    if(!check) {
        return "blablabla";
    } else if (check >= 5) {
        return "blablabla";
    }
    return "blablabla";
}
```

Since the return statement makes the JavaScript interpreter leave the current function it is in I don't see a reason to put an else statement at the end of the second example because the only way to get there is if all previously mentioned comparisons resulted false anyways.

Is this just a case of pick whatever the hell you like but be consistent at it or is there an actual rule for this?

Comment: I see no point in bloating the code, but good practices were invented to allow clueless people (including programmers) to pretend they have a clue, so...

Comment: This question seems more appropriate for the Code Review site: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: The `elseif` then `else` in a real development scenario would most likely be a faster comparison. Not in this simple example, but in a more complex one.

Comment: Alright, seems clear, cheers everyone!

Comment: return (check && (check >= 5 && '>=' || 'else')) || '!';

:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would even go one step further:

```
function doStuff(check) {
    if(!check)
        return "blablabla";
    if (check >= 5)
        return "blablabla";

    return "blablabla";
}
```

But this is a matter of taste. While I find it better to omit unnecessary `else` statements, I have also heart colleagues say that you should always put this `else` there to make the control structure clearer... But in such simple cases I would not bother putting them in.

For numeric values, though, I would prefer `check == 0` to `!check`.